Как при выборе из меню элемента менять расположение элементов формы
У меня на форме есть элементы label, textbox, button и меню с выбором языка. И нужно чтобы при выборе немецкого языка элементы выстраивались в вертикаль, а при выборе остальных в горизонталь.
Пробовала менять положения при выполнении события напрямую, то есть прям прописывать координаты, но это не удобно.

"Как" - ну это походу вы уже знаете, раз пишете "не удобно". WinForms - это про написание всего через C# код. Ну а если хотите удобства, то смотрите современные типы проектов, у которых есть XAML (WPF/WinUI/MAUI/...), там при помощи  стилей и триггеров вы можете удобно и быстро реализовать все задуманное.

Так и просится вставить элементы в StackPanel, и менять ее ориентацию

Для динамического изменения расположения элементов проще использовать контейнеры, такие как FlowLayoutPanel или TableLayoutPanel. Они автоматически управляют расположением элементов и позволяют изменить ориентацию компоновки с горизонтальной на вертикальную и обратно, не меняя вручную координаты элементов.
Вот как можно это реализовать с помощью FlowLayoutPanel:
private void SetLanguage(string languageCode)
{
    // Изменяем расположение элементов в зависимости от языка
    if (languageCode == "de") // Немецкий язык
    {
        layoutPanel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown; // Вертикальное расположение
    }
    else // Другие языки
    {
        layoutPanel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight; // Горизонтальное расположение
    }
}

